GPU Passthrough Ubuntu 24.04 error "Firmware has requested this device have a !:1 IOMMU mapping"
I’m trying to set up GPU Passthrough with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS using KVM on a HP Proliant DL360 Gen 9. The videocard I’m using is a NVIDIA GeForce 730. Ubuntu sees the videocard when I use “lspci | grep NVIDIA”.
I’ve tried 20 or 25 tutorials on the web so far and none of them seems to work. All those tutorials result in this error:
“vfio 0000:11:00.0: failed to setup container for group 32: Failed to set group container: Invalid argument”
and also in dmesg:
“vfio-pci 0000:11:00.1: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping. Contact your platform vendor”
Things I’ve tried:

Checked if Virtualization is enabled, which it is
Enabled IOMMU in /etc/default/grub
Adjusted grub to exclude the driver and device from the host so that it can be used by a VM
The videocard has been added to IOMMU group 32 with ID 0000:11:00.1

lsmod | grep vfio:
vfio_pci               16384  0
vfio_pci_core          94208  1 vfio_pci
vfio_iommu_type1       49152  0
vfio                   73728  3 vfio_pci_core,vfio_iommu_type1,vfio_pci
iommufd                98304  1 vfio
irqbypass              12288  2 vfio_pci_core,kvm

lspci -nnk:
11:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] [10de:1287] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208B [GeForce GT 730] [1043:881a]
        Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
11:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [10de:0e0f] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1043:881a]
        Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

dmesg | grep -i -e DMAR -e IOMMU
[1.590590] DMAR: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O
[64028.365834] vfio-pci 0000:11:00.1: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping. Contact your platform vendor.

/etc/default/grub:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt kvm.ignore_msrs=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Tutorials that I followed and all of them end up with the same error (Some of them were on AlmaLinux):

Virtualization - Ubuntu 22
Server-World - GPU Passthrough
Beginner friendly guide to GPU Passthrough
Github - GPU Passthrough
Luus.is - GPU Passthrough
Red Hat GPU Passthrough
Wiki Gentoo - GPU Passthrough

When I search for that Firmware error in dmesg it only shows Proxmox topics and they offer a new Promox kernel as a solution, but I’m not using Proxmox, so no solution for me. What am I doing wrong here? I’m really at my wits end here. Thanks in advance.
P.S.
I'm not very familair with GPU/PCI Passthrough, so if I forgot to provide any useful information, let me know.

That is a super old video card. Released June 2014. It would seem that the card simply does not have the needed features. You are using a 2024 OS with a 2014 card.

I've seen people use a 730, 720 and 710 to enable GPU passthrough, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Then I suggest you ask them how.

I can't ask them because there just tutorials. That's why I made a topic here so that actually people could help me out

Your comment implies you know people that made it work not that you had read some tutorial. Please edit the question and add the URL of the tutorial so anyone trying to help can read it as well.

I edited the question with the tutorials that I followed. It's not all of them because I've been spending quite some time on this and couldn't find the others ones anymore.

I managed to fix this issue by myself. I used hardware from a different brand and it works like a charm now.
